# Unexpected Java Script error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Getting Exception parsing document error in `for (var i = 0; i < Memoryval.length; i++)` line.

Can anybody help?

Below is the code.

```
 $(".rad").click(function () {
     var Memoryval = ["Fixed"];
     var CPU = ["Fixed", "Utilization", "OwnBorrow", "Custom", "Conditional"];
     var sel = document.getElementById('ddltype');
     sel.innerHTML = "";
     if (this.value == "MEMORY") {
         for (var i = 0; i < Memoryval.length; i++) {
             var opt = document.createElement('option');
             opt.innerHTML = Memoryval[i];
             opt.value = Memoryval[i];
             sel.appendChild(opt);
         }
         $("#divOwnBorrow").hide();
         $("#divFixed").show();
         $("#divUtilization").hide();
         $("#spanid").show();

     }
     if (this.value == "CPU") {
         for (var i = 0; i < CPU.length; i++) {
             var opt = document.createElement('option');
             opt.innerHTML = CPU[i];
             opt.value = CPU[i];
             sel.appendChild(opt);
         }
         $('#ddltype option[value=OwnBorrow]').prop('selected', true);
         // $("#ddltype select").text("OwnBorrow");
         $("#divOwnBorrow").show();
         $("#divFixed").hide();
         $("#divUtilization").hide();
         $("#spanid").hide();
     }
 });
```

Comment: what is exact error in console ?

Comment: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="tabs-policy", line 61 - column 41

Comment: May be you are missing a closing tag somewhere in "tabs-policy",

Comment: it is showing me error on for loop line '<' place.
any idea?

Comment: try `parseInt(Memoryval.length)`

Comment: @madalinivascu i have removed Memoryval.length with some integer value. Still getting same error.

Comment: something thinks the `<` is the beginning an HTML tag, your code is not being recognised as javascript by whatever is "processing?" it ... some Java rubbish I expect from the nature of the error message - perhaps if you describe a bit of the server environment, someone else who doesn't think java is a dead platform may be able to help you

Comment: Can you give any solution for it?
As i have already written that code in <script> tag, so i guess it should consider as script only.

Comment: @Chirag - this error isn't in a browser, is it?

Comment: for laughs, try using `&lt;` instead of `<`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, It is not in the console error of browser.

Comment: so it's not really a javascript, html or jqueery issue then, is it - have you tried using `&lt;` instead of `<` yet?

Comment: @JaromandaX Still getting same error.

Comment: @Chirag - it's something to do with springframework/thymeleaf - search for the error on your favourite search engine, see if anything interesting comes up

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have a [non breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) before `Memoryval` in that line, and it got removed while copy/paste to StackOverflow:

```
$ charinfo " " " "
U+00A0 NON-BREAKING SPACE [Zs]
U+0020 SPACE [Zs]
```

It is possible to write a non breaking space, for instance pressing <kbd>apple icon</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> on OS X will cause this character to printed. These spaces might cause problems for The Spring Framework.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?
The code is copied exactly as i have, there is no changes.

Comment: When i am removing all the spaces in for loop line, it is showing me error at ';' place.

Comment: @Chirag Which is the next line or?